# bus error on subscribing to topic on arm plattform

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Recently I changed my hardware from x86 to a Pandaboard (arm).
But now I have problems to subscribe to a "const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr&" publisher. I allways receive a "bus error" (sigbus) subscribing to the topic.

Here ist the trac of the error:

> Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus
> error.
> allInOne<ros::serialization::IStream,
> geometry_msgs::Point_std::allocator<void
>
> > &> (m=..., stream=)
> > at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/geometry_msgs/Point.h:208
> > 208         stream.next(m.z); (gdb) quit

Can anyone confirm this problem or give me a hint to solve it?

Thanks
Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46584/bus-error-on-subscribing-to-topic-on-arm-plattform/) by [RobinH](https://answers.ros.org/users/3447/robinh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the deserialization code in ROS, interacting badly with the arm hard-float support (armhf). I've had good success running ROS Electric and Groovy on Ubuntu Oneiric armel. (soft-float).

I suspect it will work with later versions of Ubuntu armel, but I haven't had time to try.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-03-04**:
I have had the same issues.  Armel seems to work very well, but when I moved to armhf, I got the bus error.  I posted a similar issue at: http://answers.ros.org/question/52326/arm-architecture-with-armhf-port-move_base-bus-error-alignment-trapexception/

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-10-10**:
Is there anyone solve this problem, I had same issue Bus Error with odom. I run in UDOO

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-10**:
This has been fixed for quite a while now. You may want to try running your node in a debugger, and if that doesn't help, open a new question and include which version of the UDOO, which version of ROS you're using, and the code for the subscriber that is crashing.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-10**:
The relevant issues where this was fixed are https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/pull/8 and https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/pull/14